# Material-UI InputLabel covers text when Input value set by another Input field

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am creating a form with [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/). The form has two sections. One is the user's shipping address, and the other is the billing address. In many circumstances the latter is identical to the former, so I provide a checkbox to automatically fill out the billing address with the shipping address. It does so by calling a function that sets the to-be-updated field's value equal to the other field's value, which is saved in the React state.

The MUI `Input` component handles the fields themselves. The `InputLabel` component is also used to label them. Normally, when values are entered in a field the `InputLabel` text moves above the field like this:

[image: InputLabel above]

However, when the checkbox is checked and the value is populated in the billing address field by typing in the shipping address field, the label fails to get out of the way:

[image]

I have been unable to solve the problem and no similar questions on Stack Overflow seem to resolve my issue. How do I fix this?

EDIT:

Here is the code from the screenshot:

```
<Grid container spacing={40} className={classes.formContainer}>
  <Grid item xs>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.sameAddressScreen2}
          onChange={this.handleSameAddressScreen2}
          value="sameAddressScreen2"
        />
      }
      label="Same as Location Address"
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
<Grid container spacing={40} className={classes.formContainer}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="locationStreetAddress1">Street Address 1</InputLabel>
      <Input id="locationStreetAddress1" name="locationStreetAddress1" autoFocus value={this.state.locationStreetAddress1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </FormControl>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="mailingStreetAddress1">Street Address 1</InputLabel>
      <Input id="mailingStreetAddress1" name="mailingStreetAddress1" autoFocus value={sameValue('mailingStreetAddress1')} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </FormControl>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is the state and the `sameValue` function that code invokes:

```
state = {
  locationStreetAddress1: '',
  mailingStreetAddress1: '',
  sameAddressScreen2: false,
};

sameValue = (field) => {
  if (this.state.sameAddressScreen2 === true) {
    let stateKey = 'location'.concat(field.slice(7));
    return this.state[stateKey];
  } else {
    return this.state[field];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) or similar that reproduces the problem and include that code in your question text.

Comment: I have added the relevant code to my original question.

Comment: The InputLabel component has a property called "shrink" - set this to true when the Input component has a value and you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: This all works just fine for me without managing `shrink` explicitly here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1pl738n94

Comment: Odd indeed. It may be some side effect of the fact that I use React state defined in the old way whereas you use `useState`? I don't see any differences that would account for the discrepancy in behavior otherwise.

Comment: The state management approach isn't going to make any difference to Material-UI. See if you can modify my sandbox to more closely match what you are doing to see if you can reproduce the issue. Are you using the latest version of Material-UI (3.9.2)?

Comment: Yes, I am using version 3.9.2. I did test your code as a separate component within my app and it does still exhibit the correct behavior. I have realized that the workaround solution I put in place quickly gets too complex when working with multiple fields, so I do believe attempting to replicate what you've done is the ideal approach. I'll work on this today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The InputLabel component has a property called "shrink" - set this to true when the Input component has a value and you will get the desired behavior.

Comment: That is true, but the `FormControl` component should be managing the `InputLabel` `shrink` property automatically.

Comment: That did it! I had to write a function that manually did the legwork of determining the state of the three inputs at any given time in order to update the state I passed into the `shrink` attribute, but it leads to the desired behavior. Strange that `FormControl` drops the ball here.

Comment: agree. is there a bug logged in maerial ui? this stinks!

Comment: Official link https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#shrink

Answer (score 3):

This problem is specified in the documentation itself.
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#shrink

Use This

```js
<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />
```

Or

```js
<InputLabel shrink>Count</InputLabel>
```